# Чи можна уникнути заміни "багато" на "велика кількість" при відмінюванні

Tags: відмінювання, числівники

чи є словосполучення "велика кількість" єдиною можливістю відмінювати слово "багато" у значенні числівника в комбінації з неперелічуваними об'єктами?
Приклад:

- багато молока – кава з великою кількістю молока

причому з перелічуваними об'єктами це працює. Перший з численних знайдених прикладів в літературі: "Якісь чарівні офіцери з багатьма орденами взяли її під руки" (Довженко)

тобто:

- багато орденів — офіцери з багатьма орденами
- багато церков — місто з багатьма церквами

в англійській чи німецькій це просто, в деяких слов'янських мовах також, проте в українській при відмінюванні доводиться замінювати слово "багато" довжилезною конструкцією. Чи є альтернативи?

Comment: Можна детальніше про _просто_ в чужомовах?

Comment: А можна джерело на те, що «багато» обов'язково треба замінювати на «велика кількість»? (У видадку збірних іменників це очевидно — «багато» трактують як прислівник і як кількісний числівник, але як кількісний числівник він до збірних іменників незастосовний, а як прислівник не може відмінюватися; але у випадку перелічуваних об'єктів я такої рекомендації в прямому вигляді не чув і Ви, здається, самі навели контрприклади.)

Comment: Думаю, очевидно, що "кава з багато молока" це неправильно. Питання саме про неперелічувані. @follower англ. a lot of milk – coffee with a lot of milk, нім. viel Milch – Kaffee mit viel Milch (з перелічуваними в німецькій вже треба відмінювати (аналогічно до української), тобто дослівний аналог був би "з багато молока")

Comment: Було б добре, јакби внесли цьу јасність в запит.

Comment: З силою-силенною молока, із тьмою-тьмущою молока, з масою молока.

Comment: Тьу, можна вживати вираз штибу [_багатиј на_](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=2027&page=90): _[кава багата на](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q="кава+багата+на"&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off) молоко_, _[місто багате на](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q="місто+багате+на"&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off) церкви_. Підходить?

Comment: Кава і багато молока. Я попросив кави і багато молока. Він приніс мені каву і багато молока...

Comment: Милозвучніше звучить "кава де багато молока".

Comment: А як щодо many, much, more? Забагато радощів не буває, але від завеликої кількості радощів бувають і сльози.

Comment: Взагалі-то "кава з великим вмістом молока". Молоко як рідина не може бути пораховане кількісно.

Comment: @Miroshko, дивлячися, що вважати "правильним". У народі кажуть "кава з багато молока", не зважаючи на думку філологічного паньства, яке від часів Сталіна відмовилося вивчати мову нації.

Comment: Кава з багатим вмістом молока - це лате.

Answer (score 3):

Якщо погратися, я б сказав ***"кава з силою молока"***. [лінк на словник, щоб мене не покарали](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

*"Кава з силою силенною молока"* — звучить гордо. :)

А якщо молока аж надто, то — *"кава з безміром молока"*.

Однак варто розуміти, що в народі кажуть "кава з багато молока" і не паряться про "правильність".

До речі, "кава з великою кількістю молока" звучить дивно. Навіть якщо ми говоримо **по-канцелярськи**, то все ж слова мають точно передавати семантику. Молоко не можна виміряти кількісно, отже, "кава з великим вмістом молока".

То тут і додам, що для не-рідини, твердої субстанції я би ще казав не "сила", а "шмат":

> Худо́би було́ шмат (Рудан.)

Comment: Ну, чисто технічно [будь-яку речовину можна виміряти кількістю](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кількість_речовини), хоча я згоден, що в побуті це не дуже поширена міра.

Comment: @Sasha Звісно так, але ж це буде кількість *грамів* молока, кількість *літрів* молока. Технічно, знову ж таки. :)

Comment: Технічно ні; _кількість речовини_ — це інше, ніж _маса_ чи _об'єм_. (Але з іншими частинами Вашої відповіді я повністю згоден.)

Comment: Кількість — це раз, два, три. Якщо ви кажете раз, два, три молока, а не раз, два, три грамів, пляшок, літрів молока, то заперечень не маю.

Answer (score 1):

**[БАГАТО](https://uk.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE)** – це незмінний прислівник, що у наведеному прикладі набуває семантичні ознаки кількісного числівника.

1. Неозначено-кількісні числівники вказують на невизначену, нефіксовану кількість чогось. **Числівники мало, чимало, багато** співзвучні із прислівниками, а числівники стільки, скільки - із займенниками, їх [належність до частини мови](http://8next.com/umova/2099-umova_154.html) **визначається на основі контексту**.
2. Лише невелика група слів, які за функціональними і деякими граматичними ознаками також зараховуються до числівників, має [інші, ніж основна система числових назв, корені](https://knowledge.allbest.ru/languages/3c0a65635b3bc78a5d43a88421316d27_0.html): **багато, небагато, мало, немало, кілька, декілька, півтора (півтори)**.
3. Числівники **багато, небагато** пов’язуються з іменниками, що означають масу, речовину, збірні й абстрактні поняття, тобто все те, що підлягає не тільки кількісному обліку, а й іншим вимірам, наприклад: багато/небагато води {солі, золота, листя, зерна, мудрості, лиха). [За граматичними ознаками](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=18807) вони подібні до власне **кількісних числівників**: не мають роду і числа, керують формою родового відмінка.
4. [Неозначено-кількісні числівники](https://pidruchniki.com/1206051647615/dokumentoznavstvo/osoblivosti_spoluchuvanosti_chislivnikiv_imennikami) **багато, мало (небагато, немало, чимало)** поєднуються з іменниками на позначення предметів, що піддаються лічбі, та нерахованих предметів і понять. Перші мають форму **родового відмінка множини**, напр.: *багато книжок, мало студентів*, а другі - **родового відмінка однини**, напр.: *мало досвіду, багато критики*.
5. Неозначені числівники **багато**, **небагато**, **кілька**, **декілька** — відмінюються як кількісні числівники **п'ять**, **шість** (але без паралельних форм), якщо вони поєднуються з іменниками, які означають конкретні предмети, що підлягають лічбі. В непрямих відмінках, крім знахідного, відмінювані числівники **багато, небагато** [узгоджуються з опорними іменниками](https://knowledge.allbest.ru/languages/3c0a65635b3bc78a5d43a88421316d27_0.html): *багатьох дерев, багатьом деревам, багатьма деревами*...

**Н.** кілька, декілька, багато
**Р.** кількох, декількох, багатьох
**Д.** кільком, декільком, багатьом
**З.** Н. або Р.
**О.** кількома, декількома, багатьма
**М.** (на) кількох, декількох, багатьох

6. [**Особливості форм числа іменників**](http://repository.kpi.kharkov.ua/bitstream/KhPI-Press/2371/2/Penkova_Ukrainska%20mova_2013_41-109.pdf)
   Речовинні іменники вживаються у множині, якщо позначають:
   а) види, сорти речовини (як правило, у професійному мовленні): *Ма­рганець застосовують у виробництві сталей, сплавів, феромарганцю, ко­льорових металів, антикорозійних покриттів тощо.*;
   б) **велику кількість речовини або великий простір, зайнятий нею:** *Широти відлічують по дузі меридіана на обидві сторони екватора від 0° до 90°. Обабіч понад трасою красуються жита.* Поширеною помилкою є немотивоване вживання множини абстрак­тних іменників. Неправильно: *Виставка вражає асортиментами продукції.* **Пам'ятаймо:** Будь-яка заміна однини множиною і навпаки повинна бути семантично і стилістично виправдана.

**"В Україні одна й та сама сфера часто регулюється одночасно [багатьма законами з великою кількістю поправок](https://www.chesno.org/t/30/verhovna-rada-parubiy.html), що неминуче призводить до колізій і проблем з тлумаченням законодавчих норм."**

Comment: Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Roman Mikhol, дякую за відповідь. Але ж мова про незліченні іменники. Зі зліченними все очевидно: «багато дерев» — «з багатьма деревами». А як бути з **незліченними**: «багато молока» — «з ???». Здається, Ваша відповідь зовсім не стосується поставленого запитання.

Comment: Sasha, думаю, треба наводити більше прикладів і завжди виходити з контексту.

Comment: А що Ви хотіли сказати додаванням «БАГАТО – це прислівник» на початку?

Comment: По-перше, додав посилання на вікі. По-друге визначив, що слово БАГАТО - це, насамперед, прислівник, що залежно від інших членів речення можуть виступати числівником чи інш.

Comment: А можете навести приклад вживання "з багатьма деревами"?